# Is the ethernet port of my NAS defective? Can't negotiate gigabit speed

Tags: networking, ethernet

This is my setup:

```
computer (gigabit) <--> router (gigabit) <--> NAS (gigabit)
```

The problem is, the NAS is not syncing at gigabit speed, but:

```
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
```

I tried switching the cable and the port on the router but nothing changed.
The full output of the `ethtool` on the NAS is:

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
```

I'm not sure I understand the part: `Link partner advertised link modes`, is that what the NAS thinks the router is advertising? Why would this happen? The router clearly support gigabit, every other device I connect to it successfully sync to gigabit.

I've tried forcing the NAS to sync at gigabit speed disabling auto-negotiation, but that resulted in the NAS unable to connect.

I've also tried to connect the NAS directly to the computer, but the computer doesn't even see anything on the ethernet port, like the cable wasn't plugged in at all. Only if I disable auto-negotiation (on the computer) and set the speed to anything up to 100 megabit full duplex (on the computer), the cable is seen as "connected" and the connection works, but if I try to set the speed to  gigabit OR I enable auto-negotiation, I get: "cable unplugged".

The NAS is a `Synology DS214se`, the router is a `ASUS DSL-N55U_D1`.
I'm not sure about the cables... I have five of them, one that came with the NAS (cat5e), one with the router, and other three. Tried them all with no success.

**EDIT:**
I've tried with a cat.7 cable, with no success...
The output for `dmesg | grep eth0` is:

```
[...]
[ 5512.538960] :eth0: link up, full duplex, speed 1 Gbps
[ 5513.630155] :eth0: link down
[ 5516.560019] :eth0: link up, full duplex, speed 1 Gbps
[ 5517.659160] :eth0: link down
[ 5520.974534] :eth0: link up, full duplex, speed 1 Gbps
[ 5521.275674] :eth0: link down
[ 5523.379207] :eth0: link up, full duplex, speed 100 Mbps
```

It tries but eventually gives up, unless I force it to stick with 1 Gbps, in such case it tries forever. Synology support stays silent :(

Comment: It might be a better question for Synology support :P

Comment: Have you tried giving the NAS a static IP and connecting directly to your PC? (May require a crossover cable depending on your network card)

Comment: @Jonno I did, except for the crossover cable, as far as I can see looking at the colors of the wires inside the cable I don't think I have any crossover cables

Comment: Crossover wouldn't be essential, you can use a patch cable if the devices can handle it, most of them do now. Did you get a connection when you did it, and was it gigabit?

Comment: @Jonno It works only if I modify the setting of the computer's ethernet interface to NOT use auto-negotiation AND to use a fixed speed of 10 OR 100. Having auto-negotiation on OR setting a fixed speed of 1000, results in the computer not seeing the cable connected at all.

Comment: Was it running at Gigabit before? Use a different patch cable cat.5e or cat.6, that supports Gigabit Ethernet. Maybe you have a defective NIC in the NAS, of the rare situation of compatibility issues. If possible, get another piece of the same NAS for tests.

Comment: @Jonno I've never seen the NAS working at gigabit speed, but until yesterday I didn't even have a router supporting gigabit so.. It was normal. The cat5e cable that came with the NAS should be more than enough for gigabit, I don't have a cat6 one to try but I will try buying one.